# Получить ID из бызы SQL текущей записи

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, binding

Есть таблица в базе данных (ID, FullName, Age). Подключаем ее в "Источнике данных". Перетаскиваем поле `FullName` на форму. Создается `DataSet`, `TableAdapter` и `CollectionViewSource`.

```
dbDataSet dataset = (dbDataSet)this.FindResourc("dbDataSet");

dbDataSetTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter userTA = new dbDataSetTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();
usersTA.Fill(dataset.Users);

myCollectionViewSource = this.Resources["usersViewSource"];
myCollectionViewSource.View.MoveToFirst();
```

Как узнать `ID` из базы для выбранного элемента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получение любого значения для выделенной текущей записи

```
int ID = ((myCollectionViewSource.View.CurrentItem as
     System.Data.DataRowView).Row as dbDataSet.ClientsListViewRow).ID;
```

Comment: _"для выделенной текущей записи"_ -- если данные привязаны к контролам в xaml, то как получить текущую запись?

Comment: контролы привязаны через `CollectionViewSource`. Например данные привязаны к `ListBox` или `DataGrid`. Когда вы выделяете `Item` в этих контролах, то в  `CollectionViewSource` меняется `CurrentItem`. Строчкой в ответе вы получите значение конкретно для выделенной строки в вашем контроле.

Answer (score 0):

Если первое значение с DataSet'а:

```
object value = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
```

Более расширенный вариант:

```
object value = dataSet.Tables[tableIndex].Rows[rowIndex][colIndex];
```

Или

```
var value = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
```

Comment: для данного подхода надо знать еще и текущие индексы