# Конвертация значения SQL Time в DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

В базе SQL есть колонки типа `Time(7)` ("Mo" и "Duration") . Как значение из этой колонки перевести в `DateTime`? Мне надо их сложить.

```
<TextBlock >
   <TextBlock.Text>
       <MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource TimeMultiConverter}">
         <Binding Path="Mo"/>
         <Binding Path="Duration"/>
      </MultiBinding>
   </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Какой тип задать в конвертере?

```
public class TimeDuration : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime mo = (???)values[0];
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм. А почему вообще SQL Time у вас пробралось в UI? Откуда оно берётся у вас? Как вы читаете значения из базы?

Comment: да из базы. Думал время в таком формате хранить, а оно, не так просто достается... Вообще когда делаю просто `{Binding Mo}`, все работает. И просто с датой получилось в другом поле. А со временем ...

Comment: Ну, а как вы читаете базу? (Ну и модельные значения не должны отображаться в UI всё же.)

Comment: В Источник данных подключил таблицу, и перетянул на форму поле

Comment: Ну, круто. А что это означает в коде? (И да, нельзя читать базу данных в UI-потоке. Подвисать будет же.)

Comment: [Вот так в коде](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486259/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-id-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B-sql-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8)

Comment: Ну используйте же уже Entity Framework, ну пожалуйста :) не пинайте остывающий труп ADO.NET..

Comment: Убрали бы его из студии, никто- бы уже не использовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя  "Представления" и "Источник данных" нужно проверить тип данных поля повращаемого адаптером.
[image: Свойства поля в адаптере]

Теперь мы знаем к какому типу его приводить.

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    TimeSpan res = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    if (values.All(v => (v != null && v.GetType() == typeof(TimeSpan))))
    {
        res = ((TimeSpan)values[0]).Add((TimeSpan)values[1]);
    }

    return res.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, в базе данных `Test` есть следующая таблица `dates`

```sql
 create table dates (Mo time(7), Duration time(7))
 insert into dates values ('10:34', '1:26')
```

Строку из таблицы `dates` загрузить в `DataTable` можно так

```
// #r "System.Data"
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

var c = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Test;";
var a = new SqlDataAdapter("select top 1 mo, duration from dates", c);
var t = new DataTable();
a.Fill(t);
var r = t.Rows[0];
var s = (TimeSpan)r["mo"] + (TimeSpan)r["duration"];   // результат: 12:00:00
```

---

Сложение `mo` и `duration` можно выполнить на сервере и вернуть результат

```
var sql = "select dateadd(MI, datediff(MI, '00:00', mo), duration) from dates";
var a = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, c);
var t = new DataTable();
a.Fill(t);
var s = (TimeSpan)t.Rows[0][0];   // результат: 12:00:00
```